# Learning "large-scale" Java technologies

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Fresh out of college, I will be starting a new job soon as a software engineer at a large Fortune 500 company.  The company uses Java and Spring MVC for its online services.

I know how to write classes in Java, but I have found that there is so much more to Java out there (e.g. Java Enterprise Edition, Java Beans, JavaBeans, JSP, Servlets, etc., etc., etc.). I would like to get at least a little familiar with "large-scale"/"corporate" Java use before the job begins in a few weeks.

How is Java used in the corporate world? Are there any suggestions on how to take my "small-scale" Java knowledge to the "large-scale"?

Answer (score 5):

You could download a few popular [open source Java projects](http://java-source.net/) and study their source.

Answer (score 5):

Some buzz words which would let you have an upper hand when it comes to an enterprise setting:

1. JMX
2. JNDI
3. JDBC
4. JAX-WS
5. JAX-RS
6. RMI
7. JPA
8. JTA

Each one of these has an official tutorial on the Oracle site which has some sample project associated with it so starting with the basis shouldn't be that big a problem.

Also, starting with [the holy bible](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) wouldn't be that bad an idea.

Good luck. :)

Comment: LOL @  the 'holy bible ' - it is a big one

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can learn project-wise in a few weeks.  I would suggest learning basic definitions for frameworks and technology names that you keep seeing.  If you know that JDBC is for connecting to databases and that struts is a web framework that will help you out even if you don't know who to use either.

Also, since your company is using Spring, I would focus on actually trying to learn as much as you can about it.  Try setting up a small example (even if you don't get it to work it would be a good exercise).